# how to insert data from one table to another table(database)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have  two databases (`test1` and `test2`) on the same server, which have the same tables (`Employee`) with the same scheme. `Employee` holds around 1.500 rows.
Now I want to copy the value of column `EmpDepID` for each PK.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE [test1].[dbo].[Employee]
SET [EmpDepID] = test2.[EmpDepID]
FROM [test2].[dbo].[Employee] test2
WHERE test2.[PK] = [test1].[dbo].[Employee].[PK]
```

as stated by @AdiInbar, the *obvious* intention of this question was something completely different.

original answer:

```
INSERT INTO [database1].[dbo].[table1]
(
    /* TODO: define columns */
)
SELECT  * /* or specify the columns */
FROM    [database2].[dbo].[table2]
```

Comment: @prince23: you're welcome - if my answer is your solution, i would be thankful if you mark it as solution :)

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of the question. **INSERT INTO** creates a new table from a query on an existing table. He's asking how to update the values in a specific column in one table based on the values from a corresponding column in matching records in another table. He actually reposted the same question an hour later, and received an answer that solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920394/how-to-update-data-in-one-table-from-corresponding-data-in-another-table-in-sql.

Comment: @AdiInbar *INSERT INTO* does **not** create a new table, whereas *SELECT INTO* does ... anyway, thanks for the clarification on that question - it was not clear at all! and ... anyway ... i will leave my answer undeleted, as it might help somebody (would i will restate my answer!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wrote that too hastily. It creates new *records*...but the OP wanted to update existing records.