# How to update data in one table from corresponding data in another table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two tables in different databases on the same database server.

Both the databases have the same structure, but different data. Database1 (Test1) is the latest, and database2 (Test2) is an old copy of the database.

- Test1 has a table called `Employee` with 3000 records
- Test2 has a table called `Employee` with  1000 records

I need to update the table in Test1 from the same table in Test2 for a particular column called DeptID, because the values in the Employee table in the Test2 DB (the old one) have been updated. So I need to update the table in the new DB from the table in the old DB which has around 1000 rows.

In other words, I need to update the `DeptID` column in the `Employee` table in the `Test1` DB with whatever values I have in the `DeptID` column in the `Employee` table in the `Test2` DB.

I know I can restore the DB itself, but that's not a solution. I need to update the values in the Test1 database from the Test2 database.

Comment: Do you want just to update the values that are on both tables? or do you want those two tables to be identical?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not clear. I guess it is difficult for you to state your problem in English clearly enough, bit don't despair! You could help it by giving some examples. Post some 5-10 rows from each table, explain what should become what, and that may just be enough for us to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If the two databases are on the same server, you should be able to create a SQL statement something like this:

```
UPDATE Test1.dbo.Employee
SET DeptID = emp2.DeptID
FROM Test2.dbo.Employee as 'emp2'
WHERE
   Test1.dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = emp2.EmployeeID
```

From your post, I'm not quite clear whether you want to **update** `Test1.dbo.Employee` with the values from `Test2.dbo.Employee` (that's what my query does), or the other way around (since you mention the db on `Test1` was the new table......)

Comment: Outstanding!! Simple, and it works (except I removed the quotes from emp2). Thanks so much!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I've done this before using subqueries, but I knew there had to be a simpler way. I just want to add that I only wanted to update a subset of the records in one table based on corresponding values in another table, which can easily be done by adding a condition to the **WHERE** clause, e.g. `WHERE Test1.dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = emp2.EmployeeID AND Test1.dbo.Employee.Department IN ('Sales','Marketing')`

Comment: But what will we do if both databases are on different server??

Answer (score 14):

```
update t2
set t2.deptid = t1.deptid
from test1 t1, test2 t2
where t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid
```

Comment: Only difference here is this version is using an alias for t2.

Comment: This worked great. For some reason, @marc_s answer did not work. Possibly because of quotes around the alias name?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
[WHERE conditions];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update test1 t1, test2 t2
set t2.deptid = t1.deptid
where t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid
```

you can not use from keyword for the mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLENAME SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLENAME;
```

Comment: The question states different databases. You haven't taken that into account. Plus the answer already has an accepted answer which works. Furthermore look at formatting your query. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

this works wonders - no its turn to call this procedure form code with DataTable with schema exactly matching the custType
    create table customer
     (
     id int identity(1,1) primary key,
     name varchar(50),
     cnt varchar(10)
     )

```
 create type custType as table
 (
 ctId int,
 ctName varchar(20)
 )

 insert into customer values('y1', 'c1')
 insert into customer values('y2', 'c2')
 insert into customer values('y3', 'c3')
 insert into customer values('y4', 'c4')
 insert into customer values('y5', 'c5')

 declare @ct as custType 
 insert @ct (ctid, ctName) values(3, 'y33'), (4, 'y44')
 exec multiUpdate @ct

 create Proc multiUpdate (@ct custType readonly) as begin
 update customer set  Name = t.ctName  from @ct t where t.ctId = customer.id
 end

public DataTable UpdateLevels(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable dtRet = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(datalayer.bimCS))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = "UpdateLevels";
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ct", dt).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                command.Connection = con;
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dtRet);
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 UPDATE Employee SET Empid=emp3.empid 
 FROM EMP_Employee AS emp3
 WHERE Employee.Empid=emp3.empid
```