# Php and MySql - copy data from one to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to know how if it is possible to copy data from one table column to another in the same database? The code below is not working with my version of MySQL but it should be working.

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `table1.column1` = 
(SELECT `table2.column2` FROM table2 WHERE `table1.city` = 'table2.city') 
WHERE `listing` ='5'
```

Do you have some idea ?
Thanks !

Guys, As I thought solution is possible with php script and solution for this problem is to make a short script which is gonna do all this up with while loop :)

Thanks everybody on joining this discussions !

---

**The solution was in `` marks between them should be column names, 
this works nice, enjoy !**

Comment: WHERE table1.city = table2.city this wont work like the way you are doing

Comment: what do you think , why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920394/how-to-update-one-table-data-from-another-table-data-in-sql-server-2005
just go through this

Comment: UPDATE table1 SET table1.column1 = table2.column2
FROM table2 WHERE table1.city = table2.city AND table2.listing ='5'

Comment: I tried this and it is not full good , I need all data to change in first table . Also it seems that this with SET table1.col1 = table2.col2 not working ....

Comment: it seems like we need php function with while , this is explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do with [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) like:

```
INSERT INTO database2.table1 (field1,field3,field9)
SELECT table2.field3,table2.field1,table2.field4
FROM table2;
```

Check [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: INSERT INTO table1 (field1) SELECT table2.field2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.city = table1.City .... this is not working

Comment: Hi Suersh it say #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.City' in 'where clause'

Comment: @LjekiDex in your question it was table1.city, in your comment it says table1.City - simple problem with uppercasing?

Comment: @LjekiDex, in your post the query is different and what i suggested in something different. You need to frame your query again as per the "INSERT...SELECT" syntax.

Comment: no there is like this uppercase in one table the problem is syntax, also I tried to do something like this UPDATE table1
SET table1.col2 = 
(SELECT table2.col2
FROM  table2 
WHERE table1.City = table2.city AND table1.Country = table2.country )   ----- > this is working but not good enough 
WHERE listing_type_sid = '6'

Comment: Suresh we need UPDATE function for this stuff, not INSERT because there is column which we want to edit .

Comment: ...it seems like we need php function with while , this is explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It reads like you're attempting to perform an update, not an insert.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.city=t2.city 
SET t1.column1 = t2.column2
WHERE t1.listing ='5'
```

In the case that you do need to copy data from one table to the other then you need to follow this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1,field2,field3) (SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM another_table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
INSERT INTO table2
   AS (SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.city = table2.city AND 
listing = 5);
```

as per column try like

```
INSERT INTO table2 (columnname1) values (SELECT columnname1 FROM table1 
WHERE table1.city = table2.city AND 
listing = 5);
```

Comment: No I do not need this , I want just to change one column .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE table1, (
    SELECT table2.city, table2.column2 
    FROM table2  ) table2
SET table1.column1 = table2.column2
WHERE table1.city = table2.city
AND listing ='5'
```