# Does having a mysqli query inside another work?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the answer to moving some data from one table to another it may not be the best, but it does work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Teacher_staff");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   // you don't need this step but it checks the select data portion
  echo $row['First'] . " " . $row['Last'] . " " . $row['Id'];

  // assign your variables, might not need this step as well

  $First = $row['First'];
  $Last = $row['Last'];
  $id = $row['Id'];

 // takes the information from the first mysqli and inserts it into the second table. 

 $sql="INSERT INTO teachers (First, Last, Id)
VALUES
(
'".addslashes($First)."',
'".addslashes($Last)."',
'".addslashes($Depart)."',
'".addslashes($id)."'

)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 // confirms that each record is added to the table.

echo "1 record added";

  }
echo "<br>";
mysqli_close($con);

echo "done";
```

Any way thanks for the help.... oh and I fixed it so that " ' " doesn't give an error.

Comment: What if a teacher's name or department contains an apostrophe?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920394/how-to-update-data-in-one-table-from-corresponding-data-in-another-table-in-sql.

Comment: Yeah if a teacher has a ' then this is a problem, but I will fix this after I even know if this is valid or not. From reading the other post, it is a phpmyadmin (think), I assume that this can translate over to PHP code on a web site?

Comment: @StuartR.Jefferys Actually this is different. He wants to populate a table from another table. Not update Table1 using Table2.

Comment: Sorry. As @Nick.BA pointed out, I'm being sloppy with "Essentially". I should have been more explicit with "Like _link_, but inserting instead of updating." Meaning just use qualified sql.names directly, not implying this is a "stackoverflow - mark as duplicate" question. Also, it is now clear that there are other aspects involved due to the context, as per the comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Teachers (First, Last, Depart) SELECT First, Last, Depart FROM Teacher_staff");
```

That's literally all you should have to run.

If you have access to your database outside of PHP (phpMyAdmin or command line), I'd recommend running that query from there.

Comment: The users will not have access to the database other than through the web site that they are interacting with.

Comment: Oh, I see. This wasn't a one-off script you're running to move data between tables?

Comment: It sort of is, the admin will load the teachers into a main table (through a web interface), but then I need some of those teachers and some but not all of the information to be set to another table so I can export it out in a valid .csv The reason I am not using just one table, is the export needs some specific information but the master table needs that information + more. Each year the admin for the school will load the new teachers into the database.

Comment: Why not just export from the master table and specify which columns to take from it? For instance, _SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM master WHERE condition = true_.

Comment: The reason is I will not be doing the export or the import, that is going to be the admin for the school. I may not be around so I wan't this to be automated as possible.