# Insert Data from a Table in another DataBase - Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO CustomersNew (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT CustomerName, Country FROM CustomersOld
WHERE status='N';
```

In above case we can insert customer data to the table "CustomersNew" which are exist in the table CustomersOld.

These two tables are in the same database

How to perform the same operation if these tables resides in two databases.

ex

table "CustomersNew" is in DB_new.

table "CustomersOld" is in DB_old.

These two databases are in two different locations.... 
how we access with security..(data bases have passwords......)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update data in one table from corresponding data in another table in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920394/how-to-update-data-in-one-table-from-corresponding-data-in-another-table-in-sql)

Comment: These data bases are in two different locations... have user names and passwords...

Comment: Your questions seems to be unclear, maybe you are looking for [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms188279.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO DB_new.dbo.CustomersNew(CustomerName, Country) 
SELECT CustomerName, Country FROM DB_old.dbo.CustomersOld WHERE status='N'

Comment: These data bases are in two different locations...
have user names and passwords...

Comment: Can you try http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Comment: I want to do it by a db script. no Excel.

Comment: if both tables schema are same, then you may go ahead with the same wizard. Please have a look at here http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-bulk-copy-and-bulk-import-and-export-techniques/