# Update SQL table with data from another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 existing tables, first one has a timestamp and data column, the second one has only a data column. Now I want to copy the data column of the 2nd table into the first but starting from a certain date overwriting the data that is already there. I have tried the following but then the values in the data column aren't updated correct.

```
UPDATE   DB_Gas
SET      DB_Gas.L_F_GAS = TEST_Table.data1
FROM     DB_Gas
JOIN     TEST_Table
ON   (DB_Gas.Timestamp > '2017-03-01')
```

Executing this changes the correct rows, but they all have the first value of the second table.

DB_GAS table:

```
Timestamp  |  L_F_Gas
2017-02-28 |  Null
2017-03-01 |  Null
2017-03-02 |  123
2017-03-03 |  456
2017-03-04 |  753
```

Test_Table:

```
data1
963
369
951
```

Result must be like this:
DB_Gas :

```
Timestamp  |  L_F_Gas
2017-02-28 |  Null
2017-03-01 |  963
2017-03-02 |  369
2017-03-03 |  951
2017-03-04 |  753
```

Comment: The join condition isn't correlating any value with the values from  `TEST_Table`

Comment: is there any related field between Test_table and DB_Gas?

Comment: Are these the only columns in the table? How are the tables related?

Comment: The complete column data1 of the table TEST_Table must be copied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update data in one table from corresponding data in another table in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920394/how-to-update-data-in-one-table-from-corresponding-data-in-another-table-in-sql)

Comment: There is no related field between the 2 tables.

Comment: Looks like I have asked something that is impossible to do by SQL, a simple copy of data from a not related table to a specific location in the table?...or not?