# How to insert data from one table to anther table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I have two tables,

```
tblA(id, num, col1, col2, col3), 
tblB(col1, col2, col3)
```

col1, col2 and col3 are the same in both tables. Now I have following sql:

```
declare @num...(same type as num)

insert into tblA
select @num, * from tblB
```

id in tblA is an indentity column.

But I got following error, 
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: That should work. It expects 4 columns and that is what you supply. Are you positive `id` is actually an `IDENTITY` column? Demo ``CREATE TABLE tblA(id INT IDENTITY, num INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT);CREATE TABLE tblB(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT);INSERT INTO tblA SELECT 1,* FROM tblB``

Comment: Please supply the `CREATE TABLE` for both tables involved. Also any triggers on the table?

Comment: Yes. It is. Here is the definition, [id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to insert data from one table to another table(database)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4919765/1563878)

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try providing the column names as well,

```
declare @num...(same type as num)

insert into tblA(num, col1, col2, col3)
select @num, * from tblB
```

Please don't worry about identity column as it will get filled automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just `INSERT` using named columns, and skip the identity column - it will be filled automatically:

```
INSERT INTO tblA (num, col1, col2, col3) SELECT @Num, col1, col2, col3 FROM tblB
```

Comment: @GLP - In that case your description of the tables' schema must be incorrect. Does `B` have additional columns you didn't mention?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is quite explicative: the SELECT and the INSERT has to have the same number of columns.

in your case

```
declare @num...(same type as num)

insert into tblA(num,col1, col2, col3)
select @num,col1, col2, col3  from tblB
```

if the key on `tblA` is not auto-generated you have to consider it in the INSERT

more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It simply based on your column name they should be of same type:

```
insert into tblA(col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3
from tblB
```